# Image not displaying after saving it into the SQLlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Could someone please help with the following issue?

I am in the process of creating an app where the client will sign on the device and then it will submit the form to an email address.  The form works and data is being submitted correctly, but i am having trouble in getting the signature to display initially before the form is being submitted.

So here is what I have so far.
 For my ExampleDBHelper.java class:

```
public static final String PERSON_FAULT_REPORTED = "faultreport";
public static final String PERSON_TECH_COMMENT = "techreport";
public static final String PERSON_SIGNATURE = "signature";
public static final String PERSON_JOB_NUMBER = "jobnumber";

public ExampleDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME +
                    "(" + PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_FAULT_REPORTED + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_TECH_COMMENT + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_SIGNATURE + " BLOB, " +
                    PERSON_JOB_NUMBER + " INTEGER)"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertPerson(String faultreport,
                            String techreport,
                            String signature,
                            int jobnumber) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PERSON_FAULT_REPORTED, faultreport);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TECH_COMMENT, techreport);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_SIGNATURE, signature);

    contentValues.put(PERSON_JOB_NUMBER, jobnumber);

    db.insert(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public int numberOfRows() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, PERSON_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}

public boolean updatePerson(String faultreport,
                            String techreport,
                            String signature,

                            int jobnumber) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PERSON_FAULT_REPORTED, faultreport);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TECH_COMMENT, techreport);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_SIGNATURE, signature);



    contentValues.put(PERSON_JOB_NUMBER, jobnumber);
    db.update(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return true;
}

public Integer deletePerson(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(PERSON_TABLE_NAME,
            PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ",
            new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
}

public Cursor getPerson(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
            PERSON_COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return res;
}

public Cursor getAllPersons() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
```

Then in my MainActivity.java class:

```
    faultReported = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EFaultReported);
    techComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETehComment);
    sigImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.custimagesig);


    jobEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCustComment);
    SimpleDateFormat calld = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyMMddHHmm" );
    jobEditText.setText( calld.format( new Date() ));

    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);
    editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
    editButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    dbHelper = new ExampleDBHelper(this);

    if (personID > 0) {
        saveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Cursor rs = dbHelper.getPerson(personID);
        rs.moveToFirst();
        String faultrep = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(ExampleDBHelper.PERSON_FAULT_REPORTED));
        String techcom = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(ExampleDBHelper.PERSON_TECH_COMMENT));
        String custsign = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(ExampleDBHelper.PERSON_SIGNATURE));


        int personAge = rs.getInt(rs.getColumnIndex(ExampleDBHelper.PERSON_JOB_NUMBER));
        if (!rs.isClosed()) {
            rs.close();
        }

        faultReported.setText((CharSequence) faultrep);
        faultReported.setFocusable(false);
        faultReported.setClickable(false);

        techComment.setText((CharSequence) techcom);
        techComment.setFocusable(false);
        techComment.setClickable(false);

        sigImage.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(custsign));
        sigImage.setFocusable(false);
        sigImage.setClickable(false);

        jobEditText.setText((CharSequence) (personAge + ""));
        jobEditText.setFocusable(false);
        jobEditText.setClickable(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.saveButton:
            persistPerson();
            return;
        case R.id.editButton:
            saveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            faultReported.setEnabled(true);
            faultReported.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            faultReported.setClickable(true);

            techComment.setEnabled(true);
            techComment.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            techComment.setClickable(true);

            sigImage.setEnabled(true);
            sigImage.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            sigImage.setClickable(true);

            jobEditText.setEnabled(true);
            jobEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            jobEditText.setClickable(true);
            return;

        case R.id.deleteButton:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.deletePerson)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dbHelper.deletePerson(personID);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentJob.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog d = builder.create();
            d.setTitle("Delete Form?");
            d.show();
            return;
    }
}

public void persistPerson() {
    if (personID > 0) {
        if (dbHelper.updatePerson(personID, 
                faultReported.getText().toString(),
                techComment.getText().toString(),
                sigImage.getDrawable().toString(),

                Integer.parseInt(jobEditText.getText().toString()))) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Form Update Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentJob.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Form Update Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        if (dbHelper.insertPerson(
                faultReported.getText().toString(),
                techComment.getText().toString(),
                sigImage.getDrawable().toString(),

                Integer.parseInt(jobEditText.getText().toString()))) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Form Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not Insert Form", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentJob.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then finally the method for creating the signature:

```
 b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignatureButton);
    signImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.custimagesig);
    b1.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);

Button.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(CreateOrEditActivity.this, CaptureSignature.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                data.getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0,
                data.getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
        signImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 625, 625, false));
    }
```

Not sure if if the CaputureSignature.class is needed?  This is only to bring up the "Sinature Pad" for the customer to sign on.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here?  Could some one please help?
Please let me know if you require more information.

Thanks Guys :-)

Comment: obviously `sigImage.getDrawable().toString()` is the problem ... also if you wana store blob then obviously `signature` should be a `byte[]` not `String`

Comment: Okay?  But i am not sure how to fix this?

Comment: Also not sure why i got a down vote?

Comment: *Okay? But i am not sure how to fix this?* there are bazillions questions about how to store BLOB

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to get String of image but you saved a byte as blob so in place of `String custsign = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(ExampleDBHelper.PERSON_SIGNATURE));` you should try `byte[] custsign = rs.getBlob(rs.getColumnIndex(ExampleDBHelper.PERSON_SIGNATURE));` and parse byte[] in bitmap and set to imageView.

**Edit**

```
byte[] custsign = rs.getBlob(rs.getColumnIndex(ExampleDBHelper.PERSON_SIGNATURE));
if(custsign.length>0){
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(custsign, 0, custsign.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}else{
Toast.makeText(this,"Image is Not Fetching ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I have done that but need to find out what to do here now?

Comment: signImage.setImageBitmap(b);
            signImage.setFocusable(false);
            signImage.setClickable(false);

Comment: i have edited my answer with some code follow this, and if you able to get Image byte then this code will definitely work.

Comment: i done what you said but not working.  I don't know if i made a mistake somewhere else in my code

Comment: I think i am making a mistake here:  public void persistPerson() {
        if (personID > 0) {
            if (dbHelper.updatePerson(personID, faultReported.getText().toString(),
                    techComment.getText().toString(),
                    signImage.getDrawable().toString(),

Comment: I have tried this signImage.getBackground().toString(), but failes with :java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: I was really hoping some one would be able to help me :-(